# Springboot app read different path when run local vs package maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, soap

So, I am developing an app and trying to use @ImportResource in the main class to refer to a xml file that contain configuration for SOAP services. When I am trying to run/debug in my local it's working just fine, but when I use maven package to build jar, it produce java.io.FileNotFoundException error.

Here is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource(locations = "jaxwsconfig.xml")
public class SoapApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SoapApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(), "/Services");
    }
}
```

Here is some errors I got when I use maven package

```
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/jaxwsconfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/jaxwsconfig.xml]
```

PS: I have a question about the filepath. Where does Java Spring refer to when I don't define absolute path? Like in this case when I just define "jaxwsconfig.xml", where does it refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jaxwsconfig.xml file is under the resource folder ie src/main/resource, you can directly give it as,

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

If suppose the file is present inside a folder inside resource src/main/resource/foldername. you have to give as,

```
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:foldername/application-context.xml"})
```